# Where should third party binaries be installed on a unix system?

Tags: bash, unix

Should they be installed to the /usr/bin/ folder, or is there a better place to put it?

Comment: How are they being installed? `/usr/bin` is generally reserved for system packaged and managed binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third-party files belong under `/opt`, as [described in the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES).

`/usr/local` is acceptable for a local administrator to place third-party files under by volition, but third-party installers and packages should use `/opt`

Comment: A comment about using `/usr/local` as that is also perfectly reasonable (depending on the purpose) would make this a better answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the distinction between `/usr/local` and `/opt` is that the former is still under the control of the system adminstrator, while regular users might be permitted to add software under `/opt/<package>` (with `/opt/{bin,lib,etc}` and so forth still reserved for the sysadmin and seemingly identical to `/usr/local/`.

Comment: It is worth noting that the FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard) is maintained by the Linux foundation, and while the _aim_ is to have _all_ Unix-like systems adhere to it, the practice apparently looks different: ["It is mostly Linux only because other OS 'vendors' do not care. We have gotten the cold shoulder from BSD more than once and commercial UNIX vendors do not care either."](http://lists.linux-foundation.org/pipermail/fhs-discuss/2012-June/000412.html) Case in point: on OSX and FreeBSD it is common to install third-party software in `/usr/local`.