# Linux dev | Good practice for program files

Tags: linux, unix, path

I use a linux environment, I'd like to know where I should be storing my code and exuctables. Obvisouly its up to the developer, but is there a standard?.. Like how on windows systems there is the Program Files directory, what is the linux equivalent?

I normally put my executables in /usr/local/bin

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is a common place for locally-written and 3rd-party software. Also `/opt/local/bin`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix standard directory to put custom executables or scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9168432/608639), [Where should third party binaries be installed on a unix system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29854278/608639), [Linux folders structure from developer perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29855034/608639), etc. Also see [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://www.google.com/search?q=Filesystem+Hierarchy+Standard) on Google.

Comment: @Barmar but I am asking about programming.. it could be any os I asked about

Comment: Your question isn't really about programming. It's about where to install software that didn't come with the OS. It's the same whether you program it yourself or download it from somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my small stuff in a directory called `~/src/`, and if it grows or uses more than one file, in a subdirectory `~/src/topicX/`.  If I start a real thorough project, it gets a directory like `~/prj/projectX/`.

Executables typically reside in the directory where they have been created.  If they are tools to be used in everyday life, I create a symbolic link in `~/bin/` pointing to the executable in its original position.

I never install anything in `/usr/local/bin/`.

You were asking if there is a standard.  No, there isn't.  There are lots of half-standards, though, and depending on who you ask, from which company, out of which school, you might hear various answers, some of them probably stating that their way is *the one* standard.

I have seen too many variants to believe that BS.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I like you idea and will take it on myself, it makes sense to me so why not?